# Not able to deserialize blob in hibernate 5 which is serialized in Hibernate 3

Tags: hibernate, serialization, deserialization

We are migrating our application from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5.4 version.

In Hibernate 3 blob has been created using below code

> ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
> ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
> out.writeObject(object);
> byte[] voBytes = byteOut.toByteArray();
> Blob voBlob = Hibernate.createBlob(voBytes);

voBlob is getting stored in column(as blob) - Oracle database table

Now after migration when we try to read the blob and deserialize it as below

> try( ObjectInputStream in = new
> ObjectInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream())) {
> obj = in.readObject();
> }

we are getting error, which says

> java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
> java.lang.String to field
> org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.SerializableProxy.identifierGetterMethodClass
> of type java.lang.Class in instance of
> org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.SerializableProxy  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2190)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2153)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1407)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2426)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2333)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2142)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2410)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2304)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2142)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2410)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2304)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2142)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
> at java.base/java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1460)    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1160)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2271)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2142)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2410)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2304)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2142)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1646)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
> at HibernateUtils.readObjectFromFile(HibernateUtils.java:78)    at
> HibernateUtils.main(HibernateUtils.java:48) error
> java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
> java.lang.String to field
> org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.SerializableProxy.identifierGetterMethodClass
> of type java.lang.Class in instance of
> org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.SerializableProxy

I could see SerializableProxy class has been changed from hibernate 3 to hibernate 5.
Can someone suggest how can we proceed now? Is there a way to deserialize the blob and reconstruct object

Comment: You need to deserialize with the exact same version as the one you used yo serialize. Then you can convert into objects that the newer version will be able to read, but as you've seen this is very brittle

Comment: Thanks Guillaume for your input. I am trying the same but while doing so I could see we need to deserialize internal object which has reference in Parrent class.


`public class XmlInboudResultVO implements Serializable {
  private HashMap<Long, Richiesta>     requestMap    = new HashMap<Long, Richiesta>(
                                                                            0);`

Here Richiesta is one more class, my observation is I need to manually again deserialize Richiesta object before setting it to a new object which newer version is ale to read.